# Dynamic navigation based on metadata and URL patterns

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is it possible to create a dynamic navigation filter based on metadata and URL patterns?

One part of the pages on our site has metadata and other part not. We need to build a dynamic navigation filter which will include page with and without metadata.

E.g

Part of pates contains metadata:

```
<meta name="content_format" content="Video"/>
<meta name="content_format" content="Audio"/>
```

Other part can be recognized by URL pattern:

```
http://test.com/.*.pdf - Document
http://test.com/blogs/.* - Blog
```

The filter should look like this:

```
Content Format
- Video
- Audio
- Document
- Blog
```

I reviewed documentation, but didn't find such opportunity.
Perhaps there are some workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dynamic navigation out of metadata or entity extraction but not both.